# 1: 1 component and user relationship

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, diagram

Hello I have a question on how to make this relationship,
I have components
and a stock of components, but I somehow need a component to be just one user, but a user can have more than one different component.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> a component to be just one user, but a user can have more than one different component.

This is a 0/1 --> many relationship.  For this type of relationship, you want a `user_id` in the `components` table.

Comment: but I wanted to have the registration of components without the user id in the components table, that is, I will have 10 components of the same id's, but only 1 user can own this 1 component, that is 10 users for 10 components of the same id

Comment: @gabriel . . . This answers the question you asked.  Your comment doesn't even make sense, because your data model has nothing about "registration".  Perhaps you should ask a new question, with a clearer explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: It's not about registration,

it is basically an id 2 component, it has 10 records in stock, that is, the 10 id 2 components belong to 10 different users.